# I posted a question that others marked as duplicate

Tags: support, duplicates

I didn't find what I was looking for when searching the web and the ServerFault site, so I posted my question:

[Multiple SPF records for multiple domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/586008/multiple-spf-records-for-multiple-domains)

Others have marked the question as a duplicate and I want to "remedy" the situation because now I am getting warnings that my account will be locked out if I keep misbehaving.

So what should I do? Delete my question? It already has an accepted answer with up-votes. How how can I remedy this situation?

Comment: `I am getting warnings that my account will be locked out if I keep misbehaving.` What warning exactly? SE changed some settings for warnings and I wonder if you're getting snagged even though you're account looks Okay. Also, I'm pretty sure questions closed as duplicates don't count against you (voting on those Qs still would).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were a victim of a drive-by closing...at least as far as my vote is concerned.  I definitely won't remember something from back in April at this point.

I upvoted your question just now and nominated it for re-opening.

The question is decent enough in that the Canonical doesn't specifically cite that only a single SPF record can be used...otherwise I would still agree with the duplicate reasoning.

Almost ALL of the questions regarding SPF records here come from devops setting up a web server with SMTP and wondering how to set one up that really have no idea what an SPF record even is.  It was only a matter of time before most of the regulars here started seeing the word SPF in a question and immediately thinking "close...dupe".  Your question just happened to be one of those that IMO is decent enough to stay but that we simply didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: Editing the "canonical" answer, or providing a better one, wouldn't go amiss either.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - just edited the canonical.

Comment: Can we (re)close this as a dupe now then ?

Comment: :) - I guess we could, but the OP is concerned they'll be sent to time out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm no longer getting unsettling warnings while posting my new question.

Comment: @TheCleaner, saw your update on the canonical, and now I see why.  Very tastefully done - thanks!